# AVD Manager Crashing

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have been having issues with AVD Manager. I am unable to load it through cmd or visual studio but able to load it through android studio. I can run the "Create a virtual drive" up until the point of actual creating where it will crash and give me this error:

```
2017-03-20 21:00:27,704 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,750 [     46]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-162.3764568, 24 Feb 2017 00:00) 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,750 [     46]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,750 [     46]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,750 [     46]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.112-b06 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,754 [     50]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -da -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.3 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\boot.jar -Didea.jre.check=false -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\DerMann\java_error_in___product_uc___%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\DerMann\java_error_in___product_uc__.hprof 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,754 [     50]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,754 [     50]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: Cp1252 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,833 [    129]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 78 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,843 [    139]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,846 [    142]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2017-03-20 21:00:27,881 [    177]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - UI scale factor: 1.0 
2017-03-20 21:00:28,666 [    962]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:29,349 [   1645]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 35 plugins initialized in 990 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:29,371 [   1667]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Games (1.0), Android NDK Support (1.0), Android Support (10.2.3), App Links Assistant (0.1), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (162.2228.14), EditorConfig (162.2228.14), Firebase App Indexing (0.1), Firebase Services (0.1), Firebase Testing (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (162.2228.14), Google Cloud Tools Core (0.2.8), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Developers Samples (0.3.1), Google Login (1.0), Google Services (0.1), Gradle (162.2228.14), Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java (162.2228.14), IDEA CORE (162.2228.14), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (162.2228.14), NDK WorkspaceManager Support (1.0), Properties Support (162.2228.14), Settings Repository (162.2228.14), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), Test Recorder (1.0), TestNG-J (8.0), YAML (162.2228.14), hg4idea (10.0) 
2017-03-20 21:00:32,623 [   4919]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1217 
2017-03-20 21:00:32,680 [   4976]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2017-03-20 21:00:32,729 [   5025]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-03-20 21:00:33,211 [   5507]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - UI scale factor changed: 1.0 
2017-03-20 21:00:33,552 [   5848]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2017-03-20 21:00:33,592 [   5888]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2017-03-20 21:00:33,643 [   5939]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:33 
2017-03-20 21:00:33,646 [   5942]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:2 
2017-03-20 21:00:33,661 [   5957]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:8 
2017-03-20 21:00:33,661 [   5957]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2017-03-20 21:00:33,692 [   5988]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2017-03-20 21:00:34,305 [   6601]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20 project components initialized in 463 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:34,306 [   6602]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:34,350 [   6646]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:703 
2017-03-20 21:00:34,651 [   6947]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:300 
2017-03-20 21:00:36,109 [   8405]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 85 application components initialized in 7750 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:36,126 [   8422]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 9218 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:36,154 [   8450]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@23b24c02 
2017-03-20 21:00:37,360 [   9656]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File C:\Users\DerMann\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
2017-03-20 21:00:37,364 [   9660]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:37,564 [   9860]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2017-03-20 21:00:37,777 [  10073]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/sdk-updates/offline-repo/offline-repo.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:37,927 [  10223]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@6ae91b97 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,032 [  10328]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,107 [  10403]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 138 project components initialized in 1280 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,148 [  10444]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,398 [  10694]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 2 module(s) loaded in 290 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,426 [  10722]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,557 [  10853]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,659 [  10955]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\DerMann\AppData\Local\Temp\StudioDownloadersys-img2-1.xml (The system cannot find the file specified) 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,662 [  10958]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:38,816 [  11112]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:39,142 [  11438]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:39,282 [  11578]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml 
2017-03-20 21:00:39,815 [  12111]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 71ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-03-20 21:00:42,951 [  15247]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 3135ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/1 sluggish 
2017-03-20 21:00:43,904 [  16200]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'MyApplication'. 
2017-03-20 21:00:44,447 [  16743]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2017-03-20 21:00:44,474 [  16770]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2017-03-20 21:00:44,505 [  16801]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/DerMann/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2017-03-20 21:00:45,795 [  18091]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 8994 ms 
2017-03-20 21:00:46,010 [  18306]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-20 21:00:46,024 [  18320]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-20 21:00:46,039 [  18335]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-20 21:00:46,045 [  18341]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-20 21:00:47,232 [  19528]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Djava.awt.headless=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\DerMann\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo.gradle, --init-script, C:\Users\DerMann\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle] 
2017-03-20 21:00:52,838 [  25134]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:52,841 [  25137]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:55,777 [  28073]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:55,796 [  28092]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:57,193 [  29489]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:57,195 [  29491]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:57,254 [  29550]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:58,582 [  30878]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:59,965 [  32261]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:00:59,967 [  32263]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,363 [  38659]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 25 Platform' (C:\Users\DerMann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk) to module 'app' 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,670 [  38966]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,716 [  39012]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,743 [  39039]   INFO - etup.post.PluginVersionUpgrade - Gradle model version: 2.3.0, recommended version for IDE: 2.3.0 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,783 [  39079]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,807 [  39103]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle successful for project 'MyApplication'. 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,849 [  39145]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'MyApplication' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,862 [  39158]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies] 
2017-03-20 21:01:06,875 [  39171]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2017-03-20 21:01:07,120 [  39416]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.generateSourcesOnly=true, --init-script, C:\Users\DerMann\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo1.gradle] 
2017-03-20 21:01:07,123 [  39419]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.generateSourcesOnly=true, --init-script, C:\Users\DerMann\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo1.gradle] 
2017-03-20 21:01:07,267 [  39563]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 7ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-03-20 21:01:07,340 [  39636]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 73ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-03-20 21:01:07,342 [  39638]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-20 21:01:07,350 [  39646]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-20 21:01:07,364 [  39660]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-20 21:01:07,383 [  39679]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-03-20 21:01:09,170 [  41466]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestSupportsInput 
2017-03-20 21:01:09,170 [  41466]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2017-03-20 21:01:12,925 [  45221]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2017-03-20 21:01:13,099 [  45395]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 4ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-03-20 21:01:13,132 [  45428]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 33ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok
```

The only warnings I see are the null pointer errors. I am unsure if that is causing the issue and don't know how to solve it.